# Django querying DB returns Queryset with swapped values

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am querying a PostgreSQL db within django, the problem is the following:

> If I have columns with values - id = 1, username = blah, desc = smth in the db, the query returns queryset of the right objects but with values - id = smth, username = 1, desc = blah

Tho I can easily append the right values to something it is a problem when I try to delete the object because on id it expects an int not a charfield. I will be glad if someone can explain to me what is happening and how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
    waiting_users = OnlineUsers.objects.all()
    print(waiting_users)

    # If there are waiting users connect to one of them
    if waiting_users.exists():
        print("There are people on the list")
        user_topair = waiting_users.first()

        pair = PairUsers()

        print(user_topair.username)
        print(user_topair.reply_channel_name)
        print(user_topair.id)

        pair.username_a = username
        pair.username_b = user_topair.reply_channel_name
        pair.reply_channel_a = reply_channel_name

        pair.reply_channel_b = user_topair.id
        pair.save()
        # user_topair.delete()
 else:
        # else put the user on the waiting list
        print("There is no one in the list")
        OnlineUsers(username, reply_channel_name).save()
        message.reply_channel.send({'text': "Please wait while we find other players"})
```

My models:

```
class OnlineUsers(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    reply_channel_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)

    def __init__(self, username, reply_channel, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.username = username
        self.reply_channel_name = reply_channel


class PairUsers(models.Model):
    username_a = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    username_b = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    reply_channel_a = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    reply_channel_b = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    score_a = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    score_b = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Where in this code are you seeing things being swapped?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  at the 3 print lines I see that they are swapped and are not like in the db

Comment: Please show your models, and any code where you are creating the OnlineUsers objects.

Comment: Added them in the post and the else where I am creating the UsersOnline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not override the `__init__` for a model; and there is no reason to do so in your case. This is almost certainly the cause of your problem. Remove that method altogether, and set the attributes using kwargs - or even better, using the `create` manager method which does the save for you:

```
OnlineUsers.objects.create(username=username, reply_channel_name= reply_channel_name)
```

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't even know that there is such option